# Meteor Future async call

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am trying return some values using Instagram api, but I have to get push to client side, the problem is these values takes awhile to load, so I need a way to call it using asynchronous method, I am not sure if I am doing right with Meteor Future?

```
Future = Npm.require 'fibers/future'
myFuture = new Future


popular_imgs = ->
  Insta.media.popular (img, err)->
    myFuture.return img


console.log(myFuture.wait())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed abit of code, and works now,

```
getInstaPop = new Future()

Insta.media.popular (img, err) ->
  getInstaPop.return img

console.log(getInstaPop.wait())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've posted your code correctly, the problem is with Coffeescript.

According to the translator at [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org), your future translates to

```
myFuture = new Future;

popular_imgs = function() {
  ...
};
```

This is obviously not what you want. The fix is simple:

```
myFuture = new Future ->
  Insta.media.popular (img, err)->
    myFuture.return img
```

Comment: Or better yet, use vanilla JS. I know CS looks tidier, but the price is that you often look at a piece of code with no clue of which part goes where, and wish you had those braces after all.